# ant.design table is not updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Trying to use this component https://ant.design/components/table/

I've put together a simple example here
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-hopper-wly0x

I expect to see a spinner instead of a link when I click on "Reload" action, but I only see `console.log` being printed.

Actually it came out to be even worse than I have locally with Mobx as a data-layer - there I have to move the cursor away from the row or back to see the changes.
Here on codesandbox I can't see the changes at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mutating the `data`, which does not force your Table to re-render. Your example will work if you add `this.forceUpdate()` before and in the end of `setTimeout`. This is ugly fix, but it might help to understand the root case.

Better solution is to extract actions into own component with own `loading` state:

```
const Actions = props => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  return (
    <span>
      {loading ? (
        <Icon type="loading" spin />
      ) : (
        <a
          href="#"
          onClick={() => {
            setLoading(true);
            setTimeout(setLoading, 2000);
          }}
        >
          Reload
        </a>
      )}
    </span>
  );
};
```

And then your actions column become:

```
    <Column
      title="Action"
      key="action"
      render={(text, record) => <Actions />}
    />
```

Answer (score -2):

Its a tricky one, what worked for me is delaying like 1000ms before performing operation to update the table

Comment: Your answer does not respond to a this question